# Blocks for beginWithCompletionHandler from NSOpenPanel

Tags: macos, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

i'm using beginWithCompletionHandler of NSOpenPanel class. My problem is that projects attribute is an invalid object inside that block. What i'm missing?

```
 NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSImage imageFileTypes]];

    [panel  beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
    {
        if (result==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
        {
            NSString *name = [panel.URL lastPathComponent];

            NSImage *aImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:panel.URL];

            if (aImage)
            {
                DLog(@"Success: %@", name);
                Sprite *sprite = [[Sprite alloc] init];
                [self.project addSprite:sprite];
            }
            else
            {
                DLog(@"Error, i can't load image %@ at path %@", name, [panel.URL path]);
            }
        }

    }];
```

I explain my problem with debugger screenshots

Before block

http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/8982/schermata062455735alle1.png

At this point all is correct, self=SpriteAnimation, project points to the correct Project instance.

http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/8982/schermata062455735alle1.png

After the if this is the state

http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/8982/schermata062455735alle1.png

Comment: What do you mean by invalid object? An object that’s been deallocated? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Hi, there isn't error messages, the problem is that if i put a breakpoint at line

`[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSImage imageFileTypes]];`

projects point at <Project: 0x10051c530>. With a break point at the  line 

`[self.project addSprite:sprite];` i saw that project is `0xc01c0000 does not appear to point to a valid object.`

Comment: Is there any chance that `self.projects` gets changed after you show the panel and before the panel is closed?

Comment: No. It's my first use of block, but if i repeat the same step without exit the program project is the same object at the same address before the if.

Comment: I just added some image to better explain my problem.

Comment: At that point the debugger is showing `self` as an instance of `NSOpenPanel` because `NSOpenPanel` is calling your completion handler block. This doesn’t mean that `self.project` is not referring to an `NSOpenPanel` instance, though. Have you tried `NSLog(@"%@", self.project);` inside your block?

Comment: Yes, i try print-object on project. At second image i see the correct object <Project: 0x10051c530>, at the third image a see that project is 0xc01c0000 does not appear to point to a valid object.

Comment: @bavarious the second images show that self is SpriteAnimation, this inside the block. The third screen, still inside the block, show that  self is a NSOpenPanel instance. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error message and what is going wrong?

```
            [self.project addSprite:sprite];
            [p addSprite:sprite];
```

Both `p` and `self.project` will be the same object (unless you've done something elsewhere to re-assign `project` between the time `p` was assigned and that block was run.

Note that you are also leaking the objects referred to be `sprite` and `aImage`.

Comment: Hi, i just removed p because it was only a test. My problem is that projects attribute is an invalid object inside that block, instead before the block is a valid usable object.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with ARC enabled, so i'm not leaking the sprite and aImage object.

Comment: I just added some image to better explain my problem.